# function based index as a conditional unique key?

Tags: oracle, constraint

I have a search table which has a generated primary key PK_ID,and also has primary keys from three or four other tables in the FK_ID column

```
CREATE TABLE METADATA  
(  
  PK_ID        NUMBER(10)                       NOT NULL,  
  OBJ_OWNER    VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)                NOT NULL,  
  OBJ_PACKAGE  VARCHAR2(35 BYTE),  
  OBJ_NAME     VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)                NOT NULL,  
  OBJ_TYPE     NUMBER(10)                       NOT NULL,  
  FK_ID        NUMBER(10)                       NOT NULL  
);
```

For example, when OBJ_TYPE = 1 then every FK_ID should be unique for that value of OBJ_TYPE.

I think I can do this with a function based index but the link to Tom Kyte's discussion on this is broken across a few web sites and I'm not sure how.
(Oracle 9.2.0.8)

A composite index will do the job.  A bonus would be if  a function based index could be used as a foreign key for the other tables.  Is this possible?

Comment: Is it as simple as f()=obj_type||','||fk_id?

Comment: Well I'm a bit embarrassed I suggested that now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure that I understand what you mean by "every `FK_ID` should be unique for that value of `OBJ_TYPE`".

If you are trying to say that each `FK_ID` has to be unique within each `OBJ_TYPE`, then it sounds like you just want a composite index on (`OBJ_TYPE`, `FK_ID`).

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_uniq_metadata
   ON metadata( obj_type, fk_id );
```

If, on the other hand, you are trying to say that if `OBJ_TYPE` = 1 then `FK_ID` must be unique but you can have duplicate `FK_ID` values if the `OBJ_TYPE` is something else, then you'd want a function-based unique index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_uniq_metadata2
   ON metadata( (case when obj_type = 1 
                      then fk_id 
                      else null 
                   end) );
```

Comment: A composite index will do the job thank you!